# how to add a value to the next cell with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a value 'x' from a table that i'm interested in. I want to first find where the value 'x' is in the table, and add a string 's' to the cell to the right of 'x'(the next column but the same row).

```
df[df.ix('x')] = s #would replace 'x' with 's'
df[df.ix('x')+1] = s #so i tried it with '+1' to indicate the same row but next the column but the syntax is wrong.
```

**UPDATE:**

example raw table data -

```
columnA    columnB
 A
 B
 X
 C
 X
 D
```

desired outcome -

```
columnA       columnB
 A          
 X            S
 X            S
 B
 X            S
 C
```

my code in a simplified version:

```
    data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/....table.xlsx', sep='\t')

    for vh in data["columnA"]:
            data[df.ix('X')+1] = s
    #obviously the '+1' syntax is wrong, how should i change it? 
    #i want S in columnB where there is X in column A
```

thanks in advance!

**UPDATE NEW CODE:**

```
   for line in f:
       for vh in data["columnA"]:
            vh = vh.rstrip()
            tmp = data[line in vh]
            tmp = tmp[list(tmp.columns[-1]) + tmp.columns.tolist()[:-1]]
            tmp.columns = data.columns
            data[tmp] = string
```

i think the syntax is wrong, anyone has any idea?
thanks

Comment: Can you post raw input data, code to recreate your df and the desired output to avoid ambiguities

Comment: how can i edit my post to include the data and code?

Comment: There is an edit button above the tags

Comment: ok  i just edited it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no `'x'` values in the last column of your DataFrame:

```
tmp = df == 'X' # boolean mask
tmp = tmp[list(tmp.columns[-1]) + tmp.columns.tolist()[:-1]] # shift the order of columns to 1 ahead
tmp.columns = df.columns # restore names order in the mask
df[tmp] = 'S' # setting the s value to the cell right after the 'X'
```

For your two-columns DataFrame it would be as simple as that:

```
df["columnB"] = df["columnA"].apply(lambda x: 'S' if x == 'X' else '')
```

Comment: hi sorry i'm new to python. why do i need to assume i have no 'x' values in the last column?

Comment: In case there is 'X' in the last column it is unclear where 'S' should be added

Comment: so if it's in a loop (my actual code is more complicated) would it be :  `if (title in vh): df["columnB"]=df["columnA"].apply(lambda data[vh]: string `  whereas  if vh from excel columnA contains the title of the string in fileA, then write the string to columnB ? (here i omitted writing 2 loops, one for the file and one for the excel)

Comment: It looks like this. However, if you had to consider multiply columns see my code with boolean mask. When dealing with pandas try to use matrix operation instead of iterations (over rows or columns).

Comment: thank you. `for line in f:   for vh in data['columnA']: if (title in vh):tmp = data[title in vh]   tmp = tmp[list(tmp.columns[-1]) + tmp.columns.tolist()[:-1]]    tmp.columns = data.columns     data[tmp] = string`  i think i got the idea but some of the syntax is wrong, do you where? thanks!